# Empty top bar icons are added every time I suspend my system in Ubuntu 21.10 with GNOME Desktop Environment

Tags: gnome, icons, 21.10, top-bar

I recently updated to Ubuntu 21.10. However, I noticed something strange:
Since the update, the top-bar icons move further and further to the left. When I restart Ubuntu, the icons are again right next to the WiFi icon like they should. I think you will understand best what I mean if you look at the following screenshot:

[Screenshot of the top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Ikd.png)

[image]

It seems like more and more empty icons are added.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Is this because of the updates? I never had this problem before.

Comment: This is a known issue with the system tray extension, see: https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/294