# Blank status bar icons appearing on top after suspend/resume in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, indicator, 21.10, statusbar

After I suspend and resume my laptop (ThinkPad P52s) running Ubuntu 21.10, blank spots appear next to the AppIndicators on the left side of the screen. These blank spots grow in number every time I suspend/resume, but go away after a reboot. If I hover over them, they have a circular highlight, but clicking them does nothing - [see image for description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyw5a.png) (the highlighted blank icon is where my cursor is placed).

I don't think the AppIndicator plugin is to blame, because the circular highlight on hover is still there with the AppIndicator plugin disabled. I have also tried [a different AppIndicator plugin](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator) but that did not help.

I found [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371307/empty-top-bar-icons-are-added-every-time-i-suspend-my-system-in-ubuntu-21-10) but none of those answers work for me. Any idea how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by switching from Wayland to Xorg on the Ubuntu login screen - after clicking username on login screen, click the small gear icon in the bottom right and go from "Ubuntu" to "Ubuntu on Xorg".